# Sony DSC-QX Remote API via NFC

Tags: nfc, sony-camera-api

In Sony DSC-QX cameras is it possible to access to the API via NFC?

I think no, and probably it's a stupid question.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry that is not possible.  The Camera Remote API is only accessible over a WiFi connection.

Comment: Hi Marlin, thank you very much.!

Is there the possibility to control it in some wired way?

Thank you again